# Visual Studio 2013 - Using Statement and Brackets off

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I'm new in at programming world, i'm trying learn about MVC language, through microsoft academy, however, i facing a little issue, when i add a new class, i can't see the "Using " statements, Namespace, or close the class with {} brackets, as you see here [My Actual Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2J5O.jpg)

I would like change my configurations to this template [Correct Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcqWi.jpg)

Could you please help me?

Thank you in Advance.
Best Regards.

Comment: i'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs

Comment: MVC supports two different languages: C# and VB(Visual Basic). The first image shows the VB version, the second shows the C# version. When creating the project (At 7'45 in the video), you choose which language will be used. Create a new project and choose the correct c# version.

Comment: that {} are in C# . The syntax is different for VB.net